# python functional programming pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, pyspark

I'm trying to translate the following scala code into python, the scala code follows:

```
val artistByID = rawArtistData.map { line =>
 val (id, name) = line.span(_ != '\t')
 (id.toInt, name.trim)
}
```

Do someone know how to use python to do so? thank you a lot!

Comment: what is line? is it something like "1234  name"?

Comment: linesFromFile=["1234 name", "5555 name2"]; [(id, name) for id,name in line.split() for line in linesFromFile]

Comment: correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is, if you have a test file with the following inputs:

```
1234 name1
1235 name2
1236 name3
1237 name4
```

---

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test_file:
    id_name_lines = test_file.readlines()

id_name_records = [(id, name) for l in lines for id,name in [tuple(l.split())]]
```

which would give you a list of pairs such as the following:

```
[('1234', 'name1'), ('1235', 'name2'), ('1236', 'name3'), ('1237', 'name4')]
```